# Filter for a 2-dimentional signal (Tension-Current curve)

Tags: python, filter, signal-processing, smoothing

I'm a Physics student so please don't judge me if my question may appear banal.
I'm currently working on a Tension-Current curve from a Frank-Hertz tube. During the experiment we had to change the tension manually in order to get the corresponding current signal. The main problem is that the acquisition rate was much higher than our tension-changing rate so we ended up with multiple current value for a single tension reading. I tried using the SavGol filter with the current values but I'm not too happy with the results. I'm looking for some kind of filter that allow me to work directly on the T-C signal rather than just considering the Current value. Here an example of the signal I'm trying to analyze: [Example of raw T-C data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Li55z.png)

---

I'm also not English-bases so forgive me if I made any mistakes.

Comment: Your many samples are not a problem.  Whatever you plan to do with this data, you'll probably be able to do it better if you keep them all.

Answer (score 0):

Two simple ideas:

1. Take the median value of Current for each value of Tension
2. Add gaussian noise to Tension for each data point, then resample to regular intervals of Tension and lowpass-filter the signal

Lowpass filtering will have artifacts on the signal edges, since digital filters compute output values based on a window of inputs.